# Where to put ~/Areas/../Views/xxx.cshtml specfic js files in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0

I am porting a website from MVC4 to ASP.NET Core 3.0

My major views have view specific complex script files which I used to put in the `/Areas/AreaName/Scripts/` directory and access them with something like.

I used to put these in a script directory in the area.

```
<script src="~/Areas/AreaName/Scripts/*ViewName*Scripts.js"></script>
```

Doing that now results in a fully dedicated file name like

```
<script src="C:\Users\..\..\..\..\*ViewName*Dripts.js"></script>
```

Which is clearly not the way to go for obvious reasons.

Do all scripts including view specific scripts now go in the `~/wwwroot/...`  directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files are stored within the project's web root directory. The default directory is `{content root}/wwwroot` . The simplest way is create area folders in `wwwroot\js` , and add area specific js flies into corresponding folder . You can also serve files outside of web root(`/wwwroot`), see [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root) for code sample .

Comment: Static means unchanging.   I don't really consider my .js files to be static anymore than I consider my c# controllers and models to be static.  But if that is the way they built it I guess its how it will fly.